# mysqli_fetch_row() funciona en localhost pero no en servidor

Tags: php, pdo

tengo un problema en mi archivo PHP al realizar una consulta a la base de datos con mysqli_fetch_row(). Cuando hago la consulta en el localhost funciona todo perfecto, pero cuando subí el sitio a mi servidor  la consulta no se hace bien y devuelve NULL, siendo que ya verifiqué que la estructura de la BD es exactamente la misma y el código también, solo cambia la información de conexión a la BD. La versión PHP del servidor (7.4) es la misma que la que he usado yo, por ende tampoco es problema de versión. Llevo días buscando una solución, modificando el código, la BD, pero sigue funcionando bien en localhost y mal en el sitio subido. Dejo adjunto el código, quizás haya algún error que salte solo si el sitio está online. Saludos.

**agregartienda.php**

```
include('bd/db.php');

global $errorVacio1, $errorVacio2;

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['numero']) && !empty($_POST['tienda'])) {


              $user = $_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname'];
              $email = $_SESSION['email'];
              $numeroserie = trim($_POST['numero']);
              $numero = substr($numeroserie,-2);
              $id_tienda = $_POST['tienda'];

              ///CONSULTA A BASE DE DATOS PARA QUE TRAIGA REGISTRO DE TIENDA
              $consulta = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM tiendas WHERE id_tienda='$id_tienda'");
              $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);
              $nombreTienda = $fila[1];
              $direccionTienda = $fila[2];

      }
}(sigue...)
```

**db.php**

```
$hostname = "nombdrehost";
$username = "usuario";
$password = "contrasena";

try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=tienda", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Database connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error al conectar con base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Tu código tiene mas problemas de fondo y es el hecho de que estás usando *mal* los métodos disponibles, una cosa es PDO y otra muy distinta mysqli, decide cual vas a usar por que `mysqli_fetch_row` pertenece a la segunda mencionada. Sin contar el hecho de que estas desaprovechando totalmente a PDO y permites consultas SQL inseguras

Comment: Si utilizo PDO cómo tendría que hacer la consulta que hice con mysqli_fetch_row ?

Comment: Explicame mejor ¿qué intentas obtener en esa línea de código? y con base en ello te puedo auxiliar

Comment: Al enviar el formulario se deben cargar datos en una tabla de "cargas". A  partir de ese formulario se obtiene un id de una tienda, con el cual se debe buscar en la tabla "tiendas" a la que tenga ese id y obtener el nombre, la dirección y otros datos de la misma, y traerlos para poder insertarlos en "cargas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Estás mezclando las utilidades de 2 clases distintas; una que es [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) y otra distintas que es [**MySQLi**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php), entonces debes delimitar e identificar cual usas y sobre esa trabajar
- Otro detalle *que aunque no es determinante para el fallo presentado*, es bueno que lo tengas en consideración es el hecho de que estás permitiendo que los valores lleguen directo del usuario a tu consulta y eso *supone un riesgo de seguridad*; entonces deberías trabajar con [**consultas preparadas**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

Una vez dicho lo anterior, propongo que tu consulta quede de la siguiente forma:

```
$consulta = $connection->prepare("SELECT nombreTienda, direccionTienda FROM tiendas WHERE id_tienda= :id_tienda LIMIT 1");
$consulta->bindParam(":id_tienda", $id_tienda, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->execute();

$resultadoConsulta = $consulta->fetch();

$nombreTienda    = $resultadoConsulta["nombreTienda"];
$direccionTienda = $resultadoConsulta["direccionTienda"];
```

Misma en la que:

- Dentro de la consulta especificamos las columnas a devolver
- Usamos el [método `fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- Dentro del método [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) pasamos el parámetro a vincular, la variable y una [*constante predefinida*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants) para identificar el tipo de dato que esperamos

La salida inicial de nuestra consulta sería un *array asociativo*, entonces estamos en condiciones de identificar el valor a asignar de esta forma:

```
$resultadoConsulta["clave"];
```

*Ya solo te resta a ti identificar y modificar de ser necesario los nombres de las columnas*

Comment: Muchas gracias! Crees que por esto funcionaba en localhost pero no en servidor? Porque antes de hacer la consulta lo probe con $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'basededatos') pero tampoco funcionó en el servidor.

Comment: Primeramente podrías probar con estas observaciones, posterior si la consulta no retorna valores puedes emplear el método `errorInfo` para obtener el **posible** fallo que esta tenga

Comment: Hice los cambios que me recomendaste y quedó mucho mejor el código, pero sigue sin poder obtener el dato de la consulta. Configuré para que se imprima qué se obtiene en $nombreTienda y no obtiene nada. En cambio en localhost sí lo obtiene y funciona bien. Muy raro.

Comment: Verifica si tu conexión esta correcta así como evalúa que los datos que intentas obtener de verdad existen en la base de datos del hosting

Comment: Ahi lo acabo de verificar, cambié algunas cosas y funcionó! Muchísimas gracias, me salvaste.

Comment: Puedes publicar si lo deseas tu propia solución